# I2C adapter to protect RPI?

Tags: gpio, hardware

I'm not good at hardware at all so apologies shall this question sound funny or weird. Is there a board or something that I could use to protect the I2C pins of my raspberry from being damaged? Just in case I connect something the wrong way - can I hinder the RPI from being killed by it? I'm going to only use the I2C pins.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Cook's [Breakout Board](http://www.thebox.myzen.co.uk/Raspberry/Breakout.html) has zener diode protection for every port. It's quite a fiddly build, though.